# Correctly free alsa mixer resources

Tags: c, valgrind, alsa

I'm writing some simple Alsa init code to setup a mixer, which I'll be using to set volume, etc. However, even basic code has memory leaks, despite using suggesting memory freeing method like `snd_config_update_free_global()`. If someone could check the snippet out and let me know what I'm missing, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void PrintAlsaError(const char * str, int error_code) {
    fprintf(stderr, str, snd_strerror(error_code));
}

int main() {
    snd_mixer_t * handle;
        snd_mixer_selem_id_t * sid;
        snd_mixer_elem_t * elem;
        const char * card = "default";

    int error_code;
    if ((error_code = snd_mixer_open(&handle, 0)) < 0) {
        PrintAlsaError("unable to open handle, error: %s\n", error_code);
        return -1;
    } else if ((error_code = snd_mixer_attach(handle, card)) < 0) {
        PrintAlsaError("unable to attach to card, error: %s\n", error_code);
        snd_mixer_close(handle);
        return -1;
    } else if ((error_code = snd_mixer_selem_register(handle, NULL, NULL)) < 0) {
        PrintAlsaError("unable to register handle, error: %s\n", error_code);
        snd_mixer_close(handle);
        return -1;
    } else if ((error_code = snd_mixer_load(handle)) < 0) {
        PrintAlsaError("unable to load handle, error: %s\n", error_code);
        snd_mixer_close(handle);
        return -1;
    }

    snd_mixer_selem_id_alloca(&sid);
    if (!sid) {
        fprintf(stderr, "couldn't get selem id\n");
    }

    if (!(elem = snd_mixer_first_elem(handle))) {
        fprintf(stderr, "no elements in mixer\n");
    }
    snd_mixer_selem_get_id(elem, sid);

    snd_mixer_close(handle);

    snd_config_update_free_global();

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the valgrind output:

```
==8389== HEAP SUMMARY:
==8389==     in use at exit: 69,442 bytes in 193 blocks
==8389==   total heap usage: 6,912 allocs, 6,719 frees, 591,848 bytes allocated
==8389== 
==8389== LEAK SUMMARY:
==8389==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8389==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8389==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8389==    still reachable: 69,442 bytes in 193 blocks
==8389==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==8389== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==8389== 
==8389== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==8389== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Some C libraries allocate stdio buffers on the heap. You might be able to free them by closing e.g. stdin/stdout/stderr if your application logic does not need them later.

Comment: you cant do anything if the library is badly written.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with alsa-lib 1.1.6. (I get a single leaked block, which is a [bug in valgrind](https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=358980).) Which versions of alsa-lib and valgrind are you using?

Comment: @CL. I'm using alsa-lib 1.1.6-1 and valgrind 3.10.0. I tried updating alsa-lib from the previous version but the problem persists.

Comment: @Jens I tried removing all I/O code and the issue persists. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Removing i/o code is not enough. Consider that stdio buffers are allocated before main() is called. Try closing all streams and check if the heap use is lower or unaffected.

Comment: Run `valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all  ./prog` to get a more detailed report.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk Thanks, but I've already done that and it points to the internals of alsa, but doesn't give much information that would be useful in determining what resources still need to be cleaned up.